# Download File via onclick on Ext.Ajax.request

Tags: c#, ajax, extjs

I'm trying to download a file by clicking on an a href link with an onClick event:

```
<a href="#download" onClick="downloadFile('@(elem.Attachment)')">@(elem.Attachment.Split('/').Last())</a>
```

in elem.Attachment, there is the full path of the file i'm trying to download.

My C# method to download the file in the Controller is the following:

```
public FileResult DownloadFile(string path)
    {
        return File(path, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, Path.GetFileName(path));
    }
```

The last method im using is the javascript function "downloadFile":

```
function downloadFile(path){
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: '/Home/DownloadFile',
            type: "post",
            params: { path: path },
            success: function (response, opts) {

            },
            failure: function (response, opts) {
                alert('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
            }
        });
    }
```

I debugged the program, and it calls the method "DownloadFile" of my controller, passing the right path.

How can i download now the returned FileResult from the Controller using the Ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

You don't is the simple answer, assuming static content. The user has to be directed to a url for the browser to do something, otherwise its just held in memory.

In the success function you can do:

```
 window.location.assign(path);
```

[window.location.assign](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot download a file through ajax. You can download a file in a new window or out of a blob object, I think it's also possible using an iframe, but with ajax it is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answers.
i fixed it now by using an ext.net component "linkButton", to which i can give a DirectEvent to call the method of the controller.
Works fine. Regards.